# Textual is not in the Applications folder after installing from the Mac App Store

Tags: macos, mac-app-store, textual

I've purchased and installed Textual from the App Store, however it doesn't appear in my Application folder and I can not find it. The App Store insists it's installed.

[image: Textual in Mac App Store shows Installed]

[image: Searching Applications for "Textual"]

I'm scratching my head - I can't find any reference to the application at all anywhere on the computer.

Comment: If you had the trial installed (e.g. extracted into Downloads folder) that's where App Store may have installed the full version.

Comment: @DanielBeck - that was it! I was running a less legitimate copy previously (not in the Applications folder) and it appears to have overwritten this old copy. Please feel free to post this as an answer and I will mark it as such. OSX is a very puzzling OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When downloading an app from the App Store, it replaces any previous instances of the application, if available. So you probably have a copy of Textual somewhere, and it got replaced.

In my case, I used the trial for a day or so, and it was stored in `~/Downloads`. That was replaced by the copy from the App Store when I bought it.

Answer (score 1):

Embrace the command line...

> find / -type d -name Textual.app -print

And let the truth be known!

This will use the find command to scour your disk from the root for a folder called Textual.app.  You may need to modify the folder argument to something like `Textual*` or `-iname *textual*` (for a case insensitive search).  Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, should I have mentioned I did this. I'm a sysadmin and I use find daily. Unfortunately nothing showing up. Tried as root and local user

Comment: @AndrewWhite, if the App Store says it's installed then there should be a folder called "_MASReceipt" beneath the App/Contents folder.  This contains the credential info for what ID was used to install an app.  Use find to search for _MASReceipt and hopefully you'll see it.

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting the Mac App Store.

1. Enable the debug menu and restart the Mac App Store.

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true
   ```
2. Choose the **Reset Application** option.

   [image: App Store Debug Menu]